# Auto updating text of a telegram bot message

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm building my first bot telegram, and I have a menu with few buttons, which when clicked, bring the user to other menus which have text that takes some data from a MySQL DB.

Since the DB is always mutating I'd like to have the text auto-updating with the new data.

Is it possible in some ways?

I'm using python-telegram-bot 13.12. My bot structure is this:

```
import time
import logging
import mysql.connector

from telegram import Update, ForceReply, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, ParseMode, Message
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


FIRST_MENU = "|||   ||   |   <b>HOME</b>   |   ||   |||\n\n"

LIVE_BUTTON = "Live"
STATS_BUTTON = "Stats"


FIRST_MENU_MARKUP = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[
     InlineKeyboardButton(LIVE_BUTTON, callback_data=LIVE_BUTTON),
     InlineKeyboardButton(STATS_BUTTON, callback_data=STATS_BUTTON)]])
LIVE_MENU_MARKUP = InlineKeyboardMarkup([
     [InlineKeyboardButton(HOME_BUTTON, callback_data=HOME_BUTTON)]])
STATS_MENU_MARKUP = InlineKeyboardMarkup([
     [InlineKeyboardButton(HOME_BUTTON, callback_data=HOME_BUTTON)]])

def getStats():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='127.0.0.1', database='storico', autocommit=True)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM Bilancio"
    cursor.execute(query,)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    stats = ""
    for row in result:
        stats += "VOLUME: " + str(row[2]) + " € "
    
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()

    return stats  

def listLive():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='127.0.0.1', database='Value', autocommit=True)
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   query = "SELECT * FROM Data"
   cursor.execute(query, )
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   unixTime = time.time() 

   liveValues = ""
   for row in result:
      if row[4] == row[6]:
         liveValues += row[3]
      elif row[5] == row[6]:
         liveValues += row[3]
   cursor.close()
   cnx.close()

   return liveValues

def values(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

  context.bot.send_message(
      update.message.chat.id,
      FIRST_MENU,
      parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,
      reply_markup=FIRST_MENU_MARKUP,
  )


def button_tap(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

  data = update.callback_query.data
  text = ''
  markup = None

  if data == LIVE_BUTTON:
     text = listLive()
     markup = LIVE_MENU_MARKUP 
  elif data == STATS_BUTTON:
     text = getStats()
     markup = STATS_MENU_MARKUP   
  elif data == HOME_BUTTON:
     text = FIRST_MENU
     markup = FIRST_MENU_MARKUP

  update.callback_query.answer()

  update.callback_query.message.edit_text(
     text,
     ParseMode.HTML,
     reply_markup=markup
  )


def main() -> None:
  updater = Updater("mytoken")

  dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
  dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("values", values))

  dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button_tap))
  updater.start_polling()
  updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Please note that the ptb dev team does not provide support for versions older than v20.4 anymore. You are encouraged to upgrade to v20.